Error: Cannot export classifier. (Error code: 3)
I try to export the classifier to assets but I get the error: Unable to export classifier. (Error code: 3) Occurs while exporting. How can I derive a random forest model, but other models cannot?
https://code.earthengine.google.com/0403c327eb1c3dd90d2e5140ad5ebb02

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. If you post your code as an image, you force each person who would help to retype your code. But that's unlikely to happen, so the Question is avoided and Questions with actual code get effort instead. Please [Edit] your Question to contain code.

You can currently only export random forest and cart classifiers.
